# Is there a simple way to generate a dxdiag file via command prompt/batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a DxDiag report that shows up right in the command prompt with a .bat file. I suppose a viable way of doing this is to create the dxdiag .txt file and display the text contained in it in the CMD window by opening the file with the 'more' command. How do I generate the dxdiag .txt file via a batch file?

Comment: Your question is off topic and not suitable for this site. The answer is clearly in reading the help information for your only command. Please delete your question and do that, thank you.

Comment: Weird that you'd complain about Compo telling you to read the help and then turn around and accept an answer that literally says "if you read the help, you'd see the option is ____". You're getting XY Problem comments because you've provided no background info about why running `dxdiag` and just reading the info there doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: To find out if I was serious, @JabbaTheHero, press the refresh button in your browser, and read the page in its entirety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `dxdiag /?`. Two of the options are `/x <outfile>` for xml or `/t <outfile>` for text.